# how to reverse some specific pairs of a list in python

Tags: python, list, reverse

I have a list of sublist and want to reverse some pairs of this list. I want to find a way to define the pairs that should be reversed based on my data. This is list of pairs:

```
split_list=[[[4, 1], [3, 0], [2, 3], [0, 3], [2, 1], [1, 4]],\
            [[3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]]
```

It has two sublists. Then I have the data that I want o use them to find where I should reverse the pairs:

```
chunk_len=[[np.array([[1., 2.]]), np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]), np.array([[0., 0.]])],\
           [np.array([[1., 2.]]), np.array([[1., 2.]])]]
```

I want to find the pairs that should be reversed based on the lengths of sublists stored in `chunk_len`. Length of first sublist in `chunk_len` is `3`. Based on this length, first sublist of `split_list` should be divided into `3` chunks. Then, I want to reverse the pairs that are in even chunks. For second sublist, it has `2` chunks and I want to reverse the pairs of second one. Finally I want to have it as:

```
[[[4, 1], [3, 0], [3, 2], [3, 0], [2, 1], [1, 4]],\
 [[3, 1], [2, 1], [0, 1], [1, 1]]]
```

I tried the following but It was not sucessfull at all:

```
cor_spl=[]
for i,j in zip (split_list, chunk_len):
    for m in i:
        cor_spl.append(m)
        if m in i[len(j):int (len(j)+len(i))]:
            cor_spl.append (m[::-1])
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding the logic behind `chunk_len`, say how to decode the information in there. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: Dear @iGian len of each sublist in `chunk_len` defines the number of existing chunks in the same sublist of `split_list` Then, I wan to reverse even chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First extract the length in a new array:

```py
chunk_len = [[np.array([[1., 2.]]), np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]), np.array([[0., 0.]])],\
             [np.array([[1., 2.]]), np.array([[1., 2.]])]]

c_n = [len(l) for l in chunk_len]
```

Then iterate over the zipped pair. Then the chance number is even, process the data to reverse the array. For each chunk there is `len(sub_list) // c_size` two-element arrays to reverse, so you should iterate over those:

```py
for (sub_list, c_size) in zip(split_list, c_n):
    for i in range(c_size):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            for j in range(len(sub_list) // c_size):
                j = i * (len(sub_list) // c_size) + j
                sub_list[j] = sub_list[j][::-1]
```

Comment: Dear @Louis Lac, can you please check the `sub_list`. It has only the last sublist.

Comment: This algorithm modify `split_list` in place, this means that the result is in `split_list`, not in `sub_list`.

Comment: Dear @Louis Lac, Is there a way to save a modified version? I mean saving what I have shown in my question.

Comment: Yes, make a copy of the original array: `result = split_list.copy()`. Then apply the algorithm on this copy.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see that in both `1st level nested` list of `split_list` list we have `4 unit step`. So logic works as follows :

**LOGIC :**
**1.** We iterate over each nested list with `step 4 unit` starting `2 index`.
**2.** For each step update `index and consecutive index` in reverse order using this command:

```
i[k+l] = i[k+l][::-1]
```

**CODE :**

```
import numpy as np

split_list=[
    [[4, 1], [3, 0], [2, 3], [0, 3], [2, 1], [1, 4]],
    [[3, 1], [2, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
]

chunk_len=[
    [
        np.array([[1., 2.]]), 
        np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]), 
        np.array([[0., 0.]])
    ],
    [
        np.array([[1., 2.]]), 
        np.array([[1., 2.]])
    ]
]


for i,j in zip (split_list, chunk_len):
    len_ = len(i)
    step_ = len_//len(j)

    for k in range(step_, len_, 2*step_):
        for l in range(step_):
            i[k+l] = i[k+l][::-1]

print(split_list)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
[[[4, 1], [3, 0], [3, 2], [3, 0], [2, 1], [1, 4]], [[3, 1], [2, 1], [0, 1], [1, 1]]]
```